# Asp.Net combine C# and Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I don't really know how to combine Angular and C#.

Like I have controllers provided with the MVC and Asp.Net, but I have also controllers provided by angular, so what should I use? The routing provided by angular-route or the routing of the MVC?
Also should in Angular I have the ng-repeat attribute and in C# I have the foreach.

I don't really know how to combine these two languages in Asp.Net?
Could someone explain me the best approach..
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of two possible ways to implement

1. **Separate `AngularJS` & `C#`application** **completely**.

   - `AngularJS` application will be stand-alone app, handle all UI logics,
     routing logic, UI template, have own view models.
   - `C#` application (I recommend you to use WebAPI/WCF or anything you're comfortable with) will **expose HTTP endpoints for AngularJS application to call**
   - **PROS**: **reusability** (the endpoints can be used anywhere, for ex: native mobile app), **light-weight** (deployment package might only contains a few js files & html files), **flexibility** (you have the ability to switch the technology easily, for ex: switch the server side to use `NodeJS` instead), server & client code could be implemented by two different teams, etc...
   - **CONS**: take much more time to develop, require strong knowledge of `AngularJS`, sometimes not easy to debug for beginner, need extra effort to secure the endpoints
2. **Mixed-mode**

   - You could combine any C# web technology (MVC, WebAPI, Webform) with AngularJS, so AngularJS code become your view or a part of your view
   - With this method, most of your application logics are still handled in MVC layer, you might reuse model classes (need to return as `JsonResult` for them to be friendly with JS app)
   - **PROS**: The application is more on `C#` code => easier for `C#` devs, easier to test (unit test, automation test your code), easier to implement authentication & authorization logic (`MVC` do it for you), faster to develop (in my opinion), etc
   - **CONS**: see **PROS** part of 1 :).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 different things. Your C# controllers will run on the server while Angular controllers will run on the browser. When you combine C# + Angular is like building to separate applications: a C# (asp.net) app that runs server-side and a JavaScript (angular) app that runs client-side.

C# controllers will handle http requests while angular controllers will coordinate the interaction of the different Angular components that are running on the browser.

I recommend you this hands-on to get started: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

Comment: Thanks, so should I use the angular-route or the MVC instead? (For routing)

Comment: You will need both because each of them will handle different things.